# Building calculator using and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to build a calculator using tkinter, I am just a beginner.
I think the problem is in the '=' button, it just doesn't work and I can't figure out why.for now i just want button from 1 to 9, plus, minus and equals buttons.when i press a number is display it in the entry but the equals button isnt working. for example if i want to do 1+2, it will show 1 and ill press the plus button then 2 and in the entry ill still see 2 instead of 3

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

class Calc():
  def __init__(self):
    self.total=0
    self.current=""
    self.new_num=True
    self.op_pending=False
    self.op=""
    self.eq=False

def num_press(self,num):
    self.eq=False
    temp=e.get()
    temp2=str(num)
    if self.new_num:
        self.current=temp2
        self.new_num=False
    else:
        if temp2=='.':
            if temp2 in temp:
                return
        self.current=temp+temp2
    self.display(self.current)

def calc_total(self):
    self.eq=True
    self.current=float(self.current)
    if self.op_pending==True:
        self.do_sum()
    else:
        self.total=float(e.get())

def display(self,value):
    e.delete(0,END)
    e.insert(0,value)

def do_sum(self):
    if self.op=="add":
        self.total+=self.current
    if self.op=="minus":
        self.total-=self.current
    self.new_num=True
    self.op_pending=False
    self.display(self.total)

def operation(self,op):
    self.current=float(self.current)
    if self.op_pending:
        self.do_sum()
    elif not self.eq:
        self.total=self.current
        self.new_num=True
        self.op_pending=True
        self.op=op
        self.eq=False

def clear(self):
    self.total=0

sum=Calc()
root=Tk()
root.geometry("345x270+200+200")
e = Entry(width=20)
e.grid(row=0,column=4)

b1 = Button(text="1",height=4,width=8,command=lambda:sum.num_press(1)).grid(row=0,column=0)

b2 = Button(text="2",height=4,width=8,command=lambda:sum.num_press(2)).grid(row=0,column=1)

# it goes up to b9

equals = Button(text="=",height=4,width=8,command=lambda:sum.calc_total).grid(row=3,column=2)

add = Button(text="+",height=4,width=8,command=lambda: sum.operation("add")).grid(row=3,column=1)

minus = Button(text="-",height=4,width=8,command=lambda: sum.operation("minus")).grid(row=3,column=0)

clear = Button(text="AC",height=4,width=8,command=lambda:sum.clear).grid(row=3,column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some information about what actually happens in your code verses what you expect to happen. "It doesn't work" isn't enough

Comment: you are right, for now i just want button from 1 to 9, plus, minus and equals buttons. the gui working fine and when i press a number is display it in the entry but the equals button isnt working. for example if i want to do 1+2, it will show 1 and ill press the plus button then 2 and in the entry ill still see 2 instead of 3.

Comment: `command=lambda:sum.calc_total` does not, at any point, actually execute the `calc_total` method.  You want `command=lambda:sum.calc_total()`, or just `command=sum.calc_total` since the method requires no parameters (which is the usual reason for needing a lambda in a case like this).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows. I have shown for only one operator and one number. You can add more to it.

```
#This is for python 3
import tkinter as tk         #Import Tkinter for python2   

from tkinter import *

root=tk.Tk()

X=StringVar()


def calculations():
    v=e1.get()
    val=eval(v)
    l=Label(root, text=str(val)).grid()

e1=Entry(root,textvariable=X)
e1.grid()

b1=Button(root, text="1", command=lambda:e1.insert(END,str(1))).grid()
bp=Button(root, text="+", command=lambda:e1.insert(END,str("+"))).grid()
b=Button(root, text="=", command=lambda: calculations()).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps